# Can I trigger 2 einsteins, two alien bees, 2 yn685, and one yn560iv with one yn662tx and one cst2?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting, strobes

I have read that you can trigger all with one yn622 on camera if you have a cst2 mounted on top *with another yn622 on the speedlights* (important part), but why would I need a second yn622 for the speed lights if they are already triggered by the yn622?

For ref: Nikon 750, mostly single studio portraits. No, I don't need to fire all at once, but I would like at least two yn speedlights, one alien bee, and one einstein to be synced.

Also for ref: I have to justify every penny spent. I would get everything that makes this job better if I can convince them of the value.

Answer (score 1):

> ... why would I need a second yn622 for the speed lights if they are already triggered by the yn622?

The YN685 has a built in radio receiver for the signal broadcast by the YN622-TX. The YN560 IV does not.

The radio in the YN560 IV is on the  YN560/RF605/RF603 II/RF603/RF602 system which is not compatible with the YN622 system. And while Yongnuo has added YN560/RF605/RF603/RF602 *receiver* capability to YN622 triggers and flashes with built in receivers made since mid-December 2014, it has not added YN622 receiver capability to the receivers in YN560/RF605/RF603/RF602 receivers and flashes.

The YN560/RF605/RF603/RF602 system is for manual only control. No TTL, 2nd curtain sync, HSS, etc. The YN560 also allows remote setting of manual power and zoom head settings and multiple groups. The RF605 includes the group functionality. Otherwise, the YN560/RF605/RF603/RF602 system only fires the flashes via radio. When YN622 triggers and flashes have their radios set to YN560/RF605/RF603/RF602 compatibility mode, they are also constrained by the limits of the YN560/RF605/RF603/RF602 system.

The YN622 system is for full flash functionality. When a flash is connected to the camera via the YN622 radio system, it is just as if the flash is sitting on top of the hot shoe with regard to TTL, HSS, 2nd curtain sync, etc. This protocol is obviously more complex than the manual only system.

If you don't need TTL, HSS, 2nd curtain sync, etc. then you might consider using a YN560-TX controller. The YN685 and YN560 IV speedlights will not need a receiver as all can be set and fired manually by the YN560-TX. If your camera has a PC terminal then you can trigger the older CST via it (The CST2 has no PC sync port). Or you can use an [RF603 II](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-rf-603-ii-released/) or [RF605](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-rf605-flash-trigger-announced/) connected to your camera's hot shoe to trigger the Yongnuo flashes and place a CST2 on top of the RF603 II or RF605. The RF603 II and RF605 have a pass through (manual 'fire" only) hot shoe that *should* allow you to stack the CST2 on top of the RF603 II or RF605 mounted on the camera's hot shoe, but I've not confirmed that anyone has been successful doing that specific combination.

Comment: It is not clear in the first sentence of the last paragraph, but the YN560 system can provide multiple flashes on a single shutter release using the YN-560TX and YN-560mkIV (not sure about other versions). The flashes must be at less than full power due to cycle time. Again, I am not sure that your sentence says that this is not available, or if I have misunderstood your intent.

Comment: @benrudgers Thanks for the catch. I didn't realize the YN560-TX enabled Multi Flash. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know except that's the flash and trigger I own and I was playing with multi-flash the other day. I'd upvote for the correction, but I already voted it up since not having TTL sort of outweighs multi-flash. On my Pentax, second shutter sync is an in camera setting. I have not tested it with the YN560 system, but it may be that it can be timed to 2nd curtain via camera despite being manual and not having a setting. May go down that rabbit hole in the near future.

Comment: If your camera will allow 2nd curtain sync without detecting a flash you may get it to work. With Canon the camera won't do 2nd curtain sync unless it detects an E-TTL flash on the hot shoe. Even with the YN622 system sometimes the YN622 unit on the hot shoe must be used to select 2nd curtain sync. The in camera setting is greyed out (although it does indicate 2nd curtain sync is selected once the change is made via the YN622C-TX).

Comment: That makes sense. I have the YN560-TX. I think it is the Nikon version, I remember reading that Nikon or Canon was preferred over the other for Pentax. Anyway, in my case there's no communication other than "fire". One day, maybe I'll know enough to use more automatic modes.